# TikZ/PGF - switching off shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

Is there a way to switch off shading for one node, in a scope where the nodes are shaded?
In other words, I want something like `shading=none`, but did not find it. Motivation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{default/.style={}}
\tikzstyle{st1}=[circle, shading=ball, ball color=red, inner sep=1.5pt]
\tikzstyle{st2}=[default, rectangle, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=2pt, draw] 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, level distance=10pt, every node/.style={st1}]
        \path node{} child {node{} child {node{} child {node[st2]{}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following result:
[image].
The problem is that the shading is inherited in the last node, which I want without shading. I thought the `default` option in definition of `st2` might help, but it does not have any effect.

The only way to achieve what I want is to add `[every node/.style={default}]` to the last `child` in the command; this resets/clears the style for all children. While writing this question, I realized that I can define `\tikzstyle{st3}=[every node/.style={default, st2}]` and use it on the last `child`. This makes it easy to use - but I would still like to know why I have to put the 'style reset' on the `child`, instead of on the `node`?

And one more thing: the reason I have `inner ysep=0.0pt` on the last node is that I actually want a single line, i.e. a box with zero width. Is there a way to achieve this in my setup, i.e. in a sequence of nodes?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, could you point me where did you find the `default` option? I looked for it in the manual without success.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino It is used on four different places in the manual, just search for `=default`. Somehow, I noticed it and I tried it for styles .. and it works, in a way :-)

Comment: @MichalKaut: The `default` style is not defined on my system (TiKZ/PGF v2.1) and throws an error. I also can't find it in the manual (only as a value that's passed to other keys, but not as an independent style). Are you using a different version of TikZ/PGF?

Comment: Oh you're right. Unfortunately when I built a mwe with that key I got: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/default' and I am going to ignore it`. Indeed, for what I understood, `default` is used to reset values to the original configuration in `baseline`, `trim left`, `trim right`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I checked my document I have have indeed defined it myself as `\tikzset{default/.style={}}` .. and forgotten about it. My fault. Should I update the post?

Comment: @MichaelKaut: Updating the post is probably a good idea. In general, it's always preferred to post complete minimal documents (so starting from `\documentclass` and containing only those things necessary to demonstrate the problem). That avoids ambiguity and makes it easier for others to come up with a solution. By the way, your definition of `default` does not have any effect on anything. `\node [default] {...}` is equivalent to `\node [] {...}`.

Comment: @Jake Good point about the default style - but I kept it in the updated example, since it is discussed here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the moment, the `shade` key is only a one way switch: It only switches shadings on, but it can't switch them off. It's easy to redefine, however:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@falsetext{false}
\tikzset{
    shade/.code={
        \edef\tikz@temp{#1}%
        \ifx\tikz@temp\tikz@falsetext%
            \tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadefalse}%
        \else%  
            \tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}%
        \fi
    }
}
\makeatother
```

Now you can say `shade=false` to deactivate the shading:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@falsetext{false}
\tikzset{
    shade/.code={
        \edef\tikz@temp{#1}%
        \ifx\tikz@temp\tikz@falsetext%
            \tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadefalse}%
        \else%  
            \tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}%
        \fi
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    st1/.style={circle, shading=ball, ball color=red, inner sep=1.5pt},
    st2/.style={rectangle, shade=false, inner xsep=1.5pt, inner ysep=0.0pt, draw}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, level distance=10pt, every node/.style={st1}]
    \path node{} child {
        node{} child {
            node{} child {
                node[st2]{}
            }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't believe this so I looked in the code .. absolutely right!  I guess no-one thought that one might want to set shading on by default and switch it off on occasion.

Comment: Much more simpler than mine: +1 `:)`

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks, this solves the problem. By the way, does it mean that there is no simple way to reset the style of a single node, using its properties (`[]`), in the same way I can reset style for its children using `child[every node/.style={}]`?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a ... ehm ... wonderful, fantastic, new shading called `none`. It basically fills the node and does nothing else. One can use it in the same way of a `ball` shading, so by means of `shading=none`; to specify the color I was in doubt if let this operation to `fill` or not, then I preferred keeping the same behaviour of the other shadings, so there's a `none shade color` key defined.

An example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@shading{none}
\def\tikz@shading{none}\def\tikz@shade@angle{0}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}
\tikzoption{none shade color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@none@color}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{none}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading[tikz@none@color]{none}{100bp}{%
  color(0bp)=(tikz@none@color);
  color(25bp)=(tikz@none@color);
  color(50bp)=(tikz@none@color);
  color(75bp)=(tikz@none@color);
  color(100bp)=(tikz@none@color)}

\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@none@color}{white}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tikzset{st1/.style={circle, shading=ball, ball color=red, inner sep=1.5pt}}
\tikzset{st2/.style={rectangle, inner xsep=1.5pt, inner ysep=1.0pt, draw,shading=none, none shade color=red}}
\tikzset{st3/.style={circle,shading=ball, ball color=blue, inner sep=1.5pt}}
% one could also avoid saying shading=none and just specifying the color, as for the ball shading
\tikzset{st4/.style={circle,  inner sep=1.5pt, none shade color=blue!50}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, level distance=10pt, every node/.style={st1}]
    \path node{} child {node[st2]{} child {node{} child {node[st2]{} child{node[st3]{} child{node[st4]{}}}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

BTW: in the original code I replaced `\tikzstyle` with `\tikzset` as per [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).

Comment: That is a lot of code to switch something off, but it works nicely. Thanks a lot. (And thanks to the pointer to the `\tikzstyle` vs. `\tikzset` issue, I was not aware of this.)

Comment: This actually is not a code to switch off the shading, but rather to override a previous shading mode with something that is still defined as a shading without behaving as a shading. Yes: my mind is complicated. `:)`