# Draw Nuclear Reactor with moving flows

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, animate

I want to draw a nuclear reactor. In [texamples.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pressurized-water-reactor/) there is a template which is pretty much what I would like to do. The code is

```
% Pressurized Water Reactor
% Author: Gloria Faccanoni <http://www.science.unitn.it/~gloria/home.htm>
%
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,landscape]{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Gray]{SIunits}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,pdftex,fixpdftex]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=0.7,
        annotline/.style = {stealth-},
        arrows1loop/.style={->,red},
        arrows2loop/.style={->,white},
        arrows3loop/.style={->,draw=Gray},
    ]
\draw[draw=Gray,double=Gray!10,double distance=4pt]
    (12,12) to[out=135,in=45](0,12)--(0,0)--(22,0)--(22,12)--(12,12)--(12,0);
\node[text width=4cm, text centered,font=\small] at (6,13)
    {Containment\\structure};
% legend
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!10] (1,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    \node[text width=4cm, font=\small,right] at (3,0.5)
        {Pressurized water\\(primary loop)};
    \filldraw[draw=blue,bottom color=blue!40,top color=Gray!30]
        (11,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    \node[text width=4cm, font=\small,right] at (13,0.5)
        {Water and steam\\(secondary loop)};
    \filldraw[draw=Blue,fill=Blue!10] (21,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    \node[text width=4cm, font=\small,right] at (23,0.5)
        {Water\\(cooling loop)};
\end{scope}
% 2nd loop --------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{scope}[xshift=7.25cm,yshift=3cm]
    % vessel left
    \filldraw[draw=blue,bottom color=blue!40,top color=Gray!30]
        (0,0) to[out=-20,in=200] (3.5,0) --
        (3.5,4.5) to[out=120,in=60] (0,4.5) -- (0,0);
    % vessel right
    \filldraw[draw=blue,bottom color=blue!40,top color=Gray!30,xshift=7cm]
        (0,0) to[out=-20,in=200] (3.5,0) --
        (3.5,5) to[out=120,in=60] (0,5) -- (0,0);
    % circuits
    \draw[draw=blue,double=blue!40,double distance=4pt]
      (1.75,-0.3) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(7,0) -- ++(0,1);
    \draw[draw=blue,double=Gray!30,double distance=4pt]
        (1.75,5.38) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(3,0) -- ++(0,-1.5);
    % arrows
    \draw[arrows2loop] (3.5,-1.3) -- (3,-1.3);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (1.75,-0.9) -- (1.75,-0.4);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (4.5,6.38) -- (5,6.38);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (7,7.38) -- (7.5,7.38);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (8.75,6.4) -- (8.75,5.9);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (8.75,-0.4) -- (8.75,-0.9);
    %
    \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,3}
        \draw[arrows2loop,xshift=7cm] (\x,3) -- (\x,2.5);
    % labels
    \draw[annotline] (2.5,-1.3) -- ++(3.5,1.3)
        node[text width=1cm,font=\small,above] {Liquid};
    \draw[annotline] (2.5,6.38) -- ++(3.5,-1.3)
        node[text width=1cm,font=\small,below] {Vapor};
    % pump
    \begin{scope}[xshift=160,yshift=-40]
        \filldraw[fill=Blue!20,draw=Blue] (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
        \node[below,font=\small] at (0,-0.5) {Pump};
        \filldraw[fill=Blue!40,draw=Blue,yshift=-0.5cm]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=Blue!40,draw=Blue,yshift=+0.5cm,rotate=180]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=Blue!40,draw=Blue,xshift=+0.5cm,rotate=90]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=Blue!40,draw=Blue,xshift=-0.5cm,rotate=-90]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
    \end{scope}
    % generator ...
    \draw[xshift=6.5cm,draw=Gray,double=Gray!10,double distance=4pt] 
        (3,4) -- ++(2,0);
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (1.8,4) -- (3.0,3.3) -- (3.0,4.7) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (1.5,4) -- (2.5,3.4) -- (2.5,4.6) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (1.2,4) -- (2  ,3.5) -- (2  ,4.5) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (4.5,3.3) rectangle (7.3,4.7);
    %labels
    \node[text width=3cm, text centered,font=\small] at (1.75,4) 
        {Steam generator\\ (heat change)};
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (8.8,5) {Turbine};
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (12.4,4) {Alternator};
    % transmission lines
    \node (aa) at (11.1,4.6) {};
    \node (bb) at (11.6,4.6) {};
    \node (cc) at (12.1,4.6) {};
    \node (dd) at (12.6,4.6) {};
    \node (ee) at (13.1,4.6) {};
    \node (ff) at (13.6,4.6) {};

\end{scope}
% 3 loop --------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{scope}[xshift=23cm,yshift=1cm]
    % circuit
    \draw[draw=Blue,double=Blue!10,double distance=4pt]
      (1,2.5) -- ++(-8.5,0) -- ++(0,+1.5) -- ++(8.5,0);
    % arrows
    \draw[arrows3loop] (-5.5,2.5) -- (-6,2.5);
    \draw[arrows3loop] (-1.5,2.5) -- (-2,2.5);
    \draw[arrows3loop] (-6,4) -- (-5.5,4);
    \draw[arrows3loop] (-2,4) -- (-1.5,4);
    % tower
    \filldraw[draw=Gray,fill=Gray!20] (1,7) to[out=270,in=80]
                  (0,0) to[out=-20,in=200]
                  (6,0) to[out=100,in=270]
                  (5,7);
    \filldraw[draw=Gray,fill=Gray!40] (1,7) to[out=30,in=150]
                  (5,7) to[out=200,in=-20]
                  (1,7);
    % labels
    \node[text width=3cm, text centered,font=\small] at (3,3.5)
        {Cooling\\tower};
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (-3.5,1.5)
        {Cooling\\water};
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (-6,3.25)
        {Condenser};
    % pump
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-10,yshift=115]
        \filldraw[fill=purple!20,draw=purple] (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
        \node[below,font=\small] at (0,-0.5) {Pump};
        \filldraw[fill=purple!40,draw=purple,yshift=-0.5cm]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=purple!40,draw=purple,yshift=+0.5cm,rotate=180]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=purple!40,draw=purple,xshift=+0.5cm,rotate=90]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=purple!40,draw=purple,xshift=-0.5cm,rotate=-90]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
%1 loop --------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=4cm]
% Reactor vessel
\filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!10] (0,-0.5) to[out=-20,in=200]
              (3.5,-0.5) --
              (3.5,4.5) to[out=160,in=20]
              (0,4.5) --
              (0,-0.5);
% circuit
\draw[draw=red,double=red!10,double distance=4pt]
  (0.1,1) --  ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-3) -- ++(5,0) -- ++(0,1.5) --
  ++(3,0) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(-3.7,0);
% Pressurizer
\draw[draw=red,double=red!10,double distance=4pt] (4.2,1.6) -- ++(0,0.8);
\filldraw[draw=Green,bottom color=red!40,top color=Green!20]
              (4,2.4) to[out=-20,in=200]
              (4.5,2.4) --
              (4.5,3.6) to[out=160,in=20]
              (3.9,3.6) --
              (3.9,2.4);
% arrows
\draw[arrows1loop] (-0.7,1) -- (-0.2,1);
\draw[arrows1loop] (-0.9,-0.5) -- (-0.9,0);
\draw[arrows1loop] (0.7,-2) -- (0.2,-2);
\draw[arrows1loop] (4.5,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
\draw[arrows1loop] (7.1,0.5) -- (7.1,0);
\draw[arrows1loop] (5.5,-0.5) -- (5,-0.5);

% pump
\begin{scope}[xshift=75,yshift=-55,fill=red!20,draw=red]
    \filldraw (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
    \node[below,font=\small] at (0,-0.5) {Pump};
    \filldraw[yshift=-0.5cm] (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
    \filldraw[yshift=+0.5cm,rotate=180]
        (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
    \filldraw[xshift=+0.5cm,rotate=90]
        (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
    \filldraw[xshift=-0.5cm,rotate=-90]
        (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
\end{scope}
% reactor core
\filldraw[fill=red!30,draw=red] (0.7,0) rectangle (2.8,2);

% control rods
\foreach \x in {1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5}
  \draw[draw=Gray,double=Gray!50,double distance=0.5pt] (\x,0.3) -- (\x,3.7);

%labels
\draw[annotline] (0.6,0.5) -- ++(-3.3,-1.5)
    node[text width=1cm,font=\small,left] {Reactor core};
\node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (1.75,5.4) {Reactor vessel};
\draw[annotline] (0.9,2.8) -- ++(-3.3,1.5)
    node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small,left=-8pt] {Control\\rods};
\draw[annotline] (4.2,3.7) -- ++(0.5,1.5)
    node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small,above] {Pressurizer};
\draw[annotline] (3.9,1.5) -- ++(1.3,-0.6)
    node[text width=2.4cm, text centered,below=-2pt,font=\small]
        {Water coolant (\unit{330}{\degreecelsius})};
\draw[annotline] (-0.1,-2) -- ++(-0.3,-0.6)
    node[text width=2.4cm, text centered,below=-2pt,font=\small]
        {Water coolant (\unit{280}{\degreecelsius})};
\end{scope}
% clouds ----------------------------------
\begin{scope}[xshift=26cm,yshift=10cm, fill=blue!10, draw=Blue,
    decoration={bumps,segment length=0.5cm}]
    \filldraw[yshift=-1.5cm,rotate=-25,decorate]
        (0,0) -- ++(-0.4,1.25)-- ++(-0.1,0.75)-- ++(0.2,0.5)-- ++(0.3,0.5)--
        ++(0.3,-0.5)-- ++(0.2,-0.5)-- ++(-0.1,-0.75)-- ++(-0.4,-1.25);
    \filldraw[xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-2cm,rotate=-30,decorate]
        (0,0) -- ++(-0.4,1.25)-- ++(-0.1,0.75)-- ++(0.2,0.5)-- ++(0.3,0.5)--
        ++(0.3,-0.5)-- ++(0.2,-0.5)-- ++(-0.1,-0.75)-- ++(-0.4,-1.25);
    \filldraw[xshift=-1.05cm,yshift=-2.15cm,rotate=-20,decorate]
        (0,0) -- ++(-0.4,1.25)-- ++(-0.1,0.75)-- ++(0.2,0.5)-- ++(0.3,0.5)--
        ++(0.3,-0.5)-- ++(0.2,-0.5)-- ++(-0.1,-0.75)-- ++(-0.4,-1.25);
    %labels
    \node[text width=1cm, text centered,font=\small] at (0.2,1.5) {Water vapor};
\end{scope}

% palo della luce
\begin{scope}[xscale=0.2,xshift=113cm,yshift=19cm,line width=1pt,Brown]
    \draw (0,0) -- (-6,-6)
          (0,0) -- ( 6,-6)
          (-1,-1) -- ( 1,-1)
          (-1,-1) -- ( 2,-2)
          ( 1,-1) -- (-2,-2)
          (-2,-2) -- ( 2,-2)
          (-2,-2) -- ( 3,-3)
          ( 2,-2) -- (-3,-3)
          ( 3,-3) -- (-3,-3)
          (-3,-3) -- ( 4,-4)
          ( 3,-3) -- (-4,-4)
          ( 4,-4) -- (-4,-4)
          (-4,-4) -- ( 5,-5)
          ( 4,-4) -- (-5,-5)
          ( 5,-5) -- (-5,-5)
          (-6,-6) -- ( 0,-5.2)
          ( 6,-6) -- ( 0,-5.2);
    \draw (-1.5,-1.5) -- (-4,-1.5) -- (-1,-1)
          ( 1.5,-1.5) -- ( 4,-1.5) -- ( 1,-1);
    \path (-4,-1.4) node (a) {}
          ( 4,-1.4) node (b) {};
    \draw[line width=1pt,Brown] (-3.5,-3.5) -- (-7.5,-3.5) -- (-3,-3)
                                ( 3.5,-3.5) -- ( 7.5,-3.5) -- ( 3,-3);
    \path (-7.5,-3.4) node (c) {}
          ( 7.5,-3.4) node (d) {}
          (-5.5,-3.4) node (e) {}
          ( 5.5,-3.4) node (f) {};
\end{scope}
% transmission lines
\draw[dashed,Gray] (c) -- (aa)
                   (a) -- (bb)
                   (e) -- (cc)
                   (b) -- (dd)
                   (f) -- (ee)
                   (d) -- (ff);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

On [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_propulsion) there is a similar image, with moving pumps, moving flows etc. [image]

How to do that using `tikz`?

Comment: Are you asking about the general process of creating animations using TikZ? Or do you have trouble with a particular part of the drawing?

Comment: @Jake: Thank you very much for your comment! I have no idea how to make it work. Somehow I think I have to use `animate` and `calc` but I don't have the foggiest on how to do it...

Comment: Take a look at the [TeXample animations](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/animations/) page, it contains lots of examples that should get you started.

Comment: @Jake: That's exactly what I did, but the thing is I don't know how to set all these up and combine them to do my animation...

Comment: You can have a look to [drawing water particles in a water column - tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101442/13304): it can give you some hints.

Comment: The demos on http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/animations/ are very nice. I see animation runs inside the PDF file. Can these animation be made to also run on a web page if one converts the latex file using htlatex to an HTML file?

Comment: »I want to draw a nuclear reactor.« Please, for safety reasons draw a picture.

Comment: @KeksDose: he he he!!! Don't worry, I can more easily design a reactor rather than drwing it! :P

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just a proof of concept; the flow was created with a very thick `dashed` line with a particular `dash pattern`; the illusion of movement was obtained using a different value for `dash phase` in even and odd slides (thanks to **Jake** for this suggestion that simplyfied my initial code):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\phase{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[orange,double=orange!60,double distance=14pt,rounded corners] (0,0) |- (6,3) -- (6,0) -- cycle;
\onslide<1-10>{
\ifodd\thepage\relax\def\phase{8pt}\fi
\draw[rounded corners,line width=8pt,dashed,blue!80!black,dash pattern={on 12pt off 6pt},dash phase=\phase] (0,0) |- (6,3) -- (6,0) -- cycle;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The animation was produced using `ImageMagick` and

```
convert -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 <file>.pdf <file>.gif
```

And here's now the idea incorporated to the actual code for the reactor; the idea is the same as with the example code above: a ten slide `beamer` document; the `\thepage` counter is used to alter the various elements and produce the illusion of movement one the animation is created. The flows are producing using a simple style:

```
\tikzset{
flow/.style={rounded corners,line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,dashed,draw=#1,dash pattern={on 5pt off 5pt},dash phase=\thepage}
}
```

The code:

```
% Pressurized Water Reactor
% Author: Gloria Faccanoni <http://www.science.unitn.it/~gloria/home.htm>
%
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,pdftex,fixpdftex}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Gray]{SIunits}
\let\square\relax

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\def\phase{0pt}
\def\altshift{0pt}
\def\bcolor{white!30!black}

\tikzset{
flow/.style={rounded corners,line width=1.5pt,line cap=round,dashed,draw=#1,dash pattern={on 5pt off 5pt},dash phase=\thepage}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=0.35,transform shape,
        annotline/.style = {stealth-},
        arrows2loop/.style={->,white},
    ]
\draw[draw=Gray,double=Gray!10,double distance=4pt]
    (12,12) to[out=135,in=45](0,12)--(0,0)--(22,0)--(22,12)--(12,12)--(12,0);
\node[text width=4cm, text centered,font=\small] at (6,13)
    {Containment\\structure};
% legend
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!10] (1,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    \node[text width=4cm, font=\small,right] at (3,0.5)
        {Pressurized water\\(primary loop)};
    \filldraw[draw=blue,bottom color=blue!40,top color=Gray!30]
        (11,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    \node[text width=4cm, font=\small,right] at (13,0.5)
        {Water and steam\\(secondary loop)};
    \filldraw[draw=Blue,fill=Blue!10] (21,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    \node[text width=4cm, font=\small,right] at (23,0.5)
        {Water\\(cooling loop)};
\end{scope}
% 2nd loop --------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{scope}[xshift=7.25cm,yshift=3cm]
    % vessel left
    \filldraw[draw=blue,bottom color=blue!40,top color=Gray!30]
        (0,0) to[out=-20,in=200] (3.5,0) --
        (3.5,4.5) to[out=120,in=60] (0,4.5) -- (0,0);
    % vessel right
    \filldraw[draw=blue,bottom color=blue!40,top color=Gray!30,xshift=7cm]
        (0,0) to[out=-20,in=200] (3.5,0) --
        (3.5,5) to[out=120,in=60] (0,5) -- (0,0);
    % circuits
    \draw[draw=blue,double=blue!40,double distance=4pt]
      (1.75,-0.3) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(7,0) -- ++(0,1);
    \draw[draw=blue,double=Gray!30,double distance=4pt]
        (1.75,5.38) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(3,0) -- ++(0,-1.5);

    % arrows
    \draw[arrows2loop] (3.5,-1.3) -- (3,-1.3);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (1.75,-0.9) -- (1.75,-0.4);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (4.5,6.38) -- (5,6.38);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (7,7.38) -- (7.5,7.38);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (8.75,6.4) -- (8.75,5.9);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (8.75,-0.4) -- (8.75,-0.9);
    %
    \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,3}
        \draw[arrows2loop,xshift=7cm] (\x,3) -- (\x,2.5);
    % labels
    \draw[annotline] (2.5,-1.3) -- ++(3.5,1.3)
        node[text width=1cm,font=\small,above] {Liquid};
    \draw[annotline] (2.5,6.38) -- ++(3.5,-1.3)
        node[text width=1cm,font=\small,below] {Vapor};
    % pump
    \begin{scope}[xshift=160,yshift=-40]
        \filldraw[fill=Blue!20,draw=Blue] (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
        \node[below,font=\small] at (0,-0.5) {Pump};
\onslide<1-10>{
\draw[Blue] (185+36*\thepage:0.5) -- (5+36*\thepage:0.5);
\draw[Blue] (95+36*\thepage:0.5) -- (275+36*\thepage:0.5);
}
    \end{scope}
\onslide<1-10>{
\draw[flow=blue,dash phase=\thepage] 
(0.5,2) -- (0.5,1) -| (1.5,0.3) -- (1.75,-0.3) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(7,0) -- ++(0,1);
\draw[flow=blue] 
(3,2) -- (3,1) -| (2,0.3) -- (1.75,-0.3);
}

    % generator ...
    \draw[xshift=6.5cm,draw=Gray,double=Gray!10,double distance=4pt] 
        (3,4) -- ++(2,0);
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (1.8,4) -- (3.0,3.3) -- (3.0,4.7) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (1.5,4) -- (2.5,3.4) -- (2.5,4.6) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (1.2,4) -- (2  ,3.5) -- (2  ,4.5) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (4.5,3.5) rectangle (7.3,4.5);
    \coordinate[xshift=6.5cm] (alta) at (7.3,4.5);
    \coordinate[xshift=6.5cm] (altb) at (7.3,3.5);
\onslide<1-10>{
\ifodd\thepage\relax\else\def\altshift{-3pt}\fi
  \draw[orange,xshift=6.5cm,yshift=-7pt+\altshift] (4.5,4.6) -- (7.3,4.6);
  \draw[orange,xshift=6.5cm,yshift=-15pt+\altshift] (4.5,4.6) -- (7.3,4.6);
  \draw[orange,xshift=6.5cm,yshift=-23pt+\altshift] (4.5,4.6) -- (7.3,4.6);
}
    %labels
    \node[text width=3cm, text centered,font=\small] at (1.75,4) 
        {Steam generator\\ (heat change)};
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (8.8,5) {Turbine};
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (12.4,4) {Alternator};
    % transmission lines
    \node (aa) at (11.1,4.6) {};
    \node (bb) at (11.6,4.6) {};
    \node (cc) at (12.1,4.6) {};
    \node (dd) at (12.6,4.6) {};
    \node (ee) at (13.1,4.6) {};
    \node (ff) at (13.6,4.6) {};

\end{scope}
% 3 loop --------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{scope}[xshift=23cm,yshift=1cm]
    % circuit
    \draw[draw=Blue,double=Blue!10,double distance=4pt]
      (1,2.5) -- ++(-8.5,0) -- ++(0,+1.5) -- ++(8.5,0);
    % labels
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (-3.5,1.5)
        {Cooling\\water};
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (-6,3.25)
        {Condenser};
    % pump
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-10,yshift=115]
        \filldraw[fill=Blue!20,draw=Blue] (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
        \node[below,font=\small] at (0,-0.5) {Pump};
\onslide<1-10>{
\draw[Blue] (185+36*\thepage:0.5) -- (5+36*\thepage:0.5);
\draw[Blue] (95+36*\thepage:0.5) -- (275+36*\thepage:0.5);
}
    \end{scope}
\onslide<1-10>{
\draw[flow=Blue!70] (1,2.5) -- ++(-8.5,0) -- ++(0,+1.5) -- ++(8.5,0);
}
    % tower
    \filldraw[draw=Gray,fill=Gray!20] (1,7) to[out=270,in=80]
                  (0,0) to[out=-20,in=200]
                  (6,0) to[out=100,in=270]
                  (5,7);
    \filldraw[draw=Gray,fill=Gray!40] (1,7) to[out=30,in=150]
                  (5,7) to[out=200,in=-20]
                  (1,7);
    % labels
    \node[text width=3cm, text centered,font=\small] at (3,3.5)
        {Cooling\\tower};
\end{scope}

%1 loop --------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=4cm]
% Reactor vessel
\filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!10] (0,-0.5) to[out=-20,in=200]
              (3.5,-0.5) --
              (3.5,4.5) to[out=160,in=20]
              (0,4.5) --
              (0,-0.5);
% circuit
\draw[draw=red,double=red!10,double distance=4pt]
  (0.1,1) --  ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-3) -- ++(5,0) -- ++(0,1.5) --
  ++(3,0) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(-3.7,0);

% Pressurizer
\draw[draw=red,double=red!10,double distance=4pt] (4.2,1.6) -- ++(0,0.8);
\filldraw[draw=Green,bottom color=red!40,top color=Green!20]
              (4,2.4) to[out=-20,in=200]
              (4.5,2.4) --
              (4.5,3.6) to[out=160,in=20]
              (3.9,3.6) --
              (3.9,2.4);

% pump
\begin{scope}[xshift=75,yshift=-55,fill=red!20,draw=red]
    \filldraw (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
    \node[below,font=\small] at (0,-0.5) {Pump};
\onslide<1-10>{
\draw[red] (185+36*\thepage:0.5) -- (5+36*\thepage:0.5);
\draw[red] (95+36*\thepage:0.5) -- (275+36*\thepage:0.5);
}
\end{scope}
% reactor core
\filldraw[fill=red!30,draw=red] (0.7,0) rectangle (2.8,2);

% control rods
\foreach \x in {1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5}
  \draw[draw=Gray,double=Gray!50,double distance=0.5pt] (\x,0.3) -- (\x,3.7);
\onslide<1-10>{
\draw[flow=red] 
(0.1,1) --  ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-3) -- ++(5,0) -- ++(0,1.5) --
  ++(3,0) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(-4,0) --  ++(0,2.5) -- ++(-0.8,0) -- ++(0,-4.3) -- 
  ++(-0.55,0) --  ++(0,4.3) -- ++(-0.55,0) --  ++(0,-4.3) -- 
  ++(-0.7,0) -- ++(0,1.3) -- ++(-0.15,0);
}

%labels
\draw[annotline] (0.6,0.5) -- ++(-3.3,-1.5)
    node[text width=1cm,font=\small,left] {Reactor core};
\node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (1.75,5.4) {Reactor vessel};
\draw[annotline] (0.9,2.8) -- ++(-3.3,1.5)
    node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small,left=-8pt] {Control\\rods};
\draw[annotline] (4.2,3.7) -- ++(0.5,1.5)
    node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small,above] {Pressurizer};
\draw[annotline] (3.9,1.5) -- ++(1.3,-0.6)
    node[text width=2.4cm, text centered,below=-2pt,font=\small]
        {Water coolant (\unit{330}{\degreecelsius})};
\draw[annotline] (-0.1,-2) -- ++(-0.3,-0.6)
    node[text width=2.4cm, text centered,below=-2pt,font=\small]
        {Water coolant (\unit{280}{\degreecelsius})};
\end{scope}

% palo della luce
\begin{scope}[xscale=0.2,xshift=128cm,yshift=16cm,line width=1pt,Brown]
    \draw (0,0) -- (-6,-6)
          (0,0) -- ( 6,-6)
          (-1,-1) -- ( 1,-1)
          (-1,-1) -- ( 2,-2)
          ( 1,-1) -- (-2,-2)
          (-2,-2) -- ( 2,-2)
          (-2,-2) -- ( 3,-3)
          ( 2,-2) -- (-3,-3)
          ( 3,-3) -- (-3,-3)
          (-3,-3) -- ( 4,-4)
          ( 3,-3) -- (-4,-4)
          ( 4,-4) -- (-4,-4)
          (-4,-4) -- ( 5,-5)
          ( 4,-4) -- (-5,-5)
          ( 5,-5) -- (-5,-5)
          (-6,-6) -- ( 0,-5.2)
          ( 6,-6) -- ( 0,-5.2);
    \draw (-1.5,-1.5) -- (-4,-1.5) -- (-1,-1)
          ( 1.5,-1.5) -- ( 4,-1.5) -- ( 1,-1);
    \path (-4,-1.4) node (a) {}
          ( 4,-1.4) node (b) {};
    \path (-7.5,-3.4) node (c) {}
          ( 7.5,-3.4) node (d) {}
          (-5.5,-3.4) node (e) {}
          ( 5.5,-3.4) node (f) {};
\end{scope}
% transmission lines (alternator-tower)
\draw[Gray]
                   (alta) to[out=30,in=260] (a)
                   (altb) to[out=30,in=260] (b);

% building
\begin{scope}[xscale=0.2,xshift=100cm,yshift=17cm]
\filldraw (-3.5,0) rectangle (0.6,2);
\onslide<1-10>{
\ifnum\thepage<7\relax
\else
\ifnum\thepage=7\relax
  \def\bcolor{white!50!black}
\else\ifnum\thepage=8\relax
  \def\bcolor{white!80!black}
\else\ifnum\thepage<11\relax
  \def\bcolor{white!97!black}
\fi\fi\fi\fi
\foreach \piso in {0.1,0.5,...,1.7}
  {
  \filldraw[\bcolor] (-3.05,\piso) rectangle (-2,\piso+0.2);
  \filldraw[\bcolor] (-1.15,\piso) rectangle (0.1,\piso+0.2);
  }
}
% transmission lines (tower-building)
\draw[Gray]
                   (a) to[out=185,in=-20] (-0.7,0)
                   (b) to[out=182,in=-20] (0.6,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jake great suggestion! This also allowed me to simplify the code. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I used your code and I saw that the pdf file has 10 slides. I supposse that's where the `ImakeMagik` comes... What's this? Is it a programm? I searched for it but I wasn't able to find anything... Only the `ImageMaker` or perhaps `Imagemagick` which is http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: @Thanos Yes, `convert` is supplied by ImageMagick.

Comment: @TimN: Thank you very much! Tha thing is that I expected to show me a terminal but it doesn't... Anyway, I'll see what I can do... What concerns me is how to edit the reactor's big code to make the animation!

Comment: @Thanos Sorry about the spelling issue with `ImageMagick`; I've fixed it in my updated answer. Also, I've incorporated my idea to the actual code of the reactor to produce the animated flows.

Comment: @Thanos I've updated my answer providing animations for some other elements.

Comment: @Jake Thanks! You're right about the need for more than two steps; however, I am a little tired for today with this code, so I will make the changes tomorrow.

Comment: @Jake I made a little change and I hope now it looks better; there's still some improvement that could be done when the animation loops, but I think I am gonna leave the code as it is now.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Oh my god... I've been trying all day long and all I've managed to do was the rotation of the pump... But you did sooooo much... At least there are the steam clouds left for me... Thank you very much for your time and help! You are awesome!!!

Comment: @Thanos You're welcome! I made yet another update; now the flow transition is smooth when the animation loops.

Answer (score 26):

I used your question to finally try out the **animate** package. The "animation" is in an external file, it uses the **standalone** package and the `markings` decoration of **tikz**:

### "Animation" code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{reddot/.style={decoration={markings, mark=between positions #1 and 1 step 0.01 with {\fill[red] circle(0.05);}}}}

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
{   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[yellow!10,draw=yellow!50!black] (-1,-7) rectangle node[yellow!50!black] {reactor} (7,3);
        \draw[reddot=\x/1000,postaction={decorate}]  (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (6,2) -- (6,-4) arc (360:180:2) -- (0,-3) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Then I used this "animation" consisting of 10 single pages in a PDF file *(anim.pdf)* to put it in the real document:

### Document code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{center}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{10}{anim}{}{}
        \caption{reactor cycle}
    \end{figure}
\end{center}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

### Output

(this is a picture created with *[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)*, as one can't upload PDFs)

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** Editing the given code is quite easy, I did it for *loop 1*, the reactor loop. The path to be animated is labeled *circuit*. All I did was:

- copy the *circuit* code, to use it once for the pipes and once for the flow (one could also use just one and add the flow as a `postaction`)
- add a little `rounded corners` to make it look nicer
- comment out all the arrows
- I decided to use 10 pictures, so I added a `foreach` loop outside the picture
- changed class to **standalone**
- got rid of the capitalized colors (e.g. `Green`) as I got a *package option clash* for **xcolor**
- replaced **SIunits** with **siunitx**
- used **textcomp** for Celsius symbol (one could also use e.g. `\SI{42}{\celsius}`)
- used Jake's suggestion

The `dash pattern` I used is 6pt long (4pt on + 2pt off), so I set the `dash phase` to `\x/10*6pt`. This way the dashes will be shifted `0%,10%,...,90%` of one cycle letting the animation be smooth.

### "Animation" code

```
% Pressurized Water Reactor
% Author: Gloria Faccanoni <http://www.science.unitn.it/~gloria/home.htm>
%
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {0,...,9}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=0.7,
        annotline/.style = {stealth-},
        arrows1loop/.style={->,red},
        arrows2loop/.style={->,white},
        arrows3loop/.style={->,draw=gray},
    ]
\draw[draw=gray,double=gray!10,double distance=4pt]
    (12,12) to[out=135,in=45](0,12)--(0,0)--(22,0)--(22,12)--(12,12)--(12,0);
\node[text width=4cm, text centered,font=\small] at (6,13)
    {Containment\\structure};
% legend
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!10] (1,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    \node[text width=4cm, font=\small,right] at (3,0.5)
        {Pressurized water\\(primary loop)};
    \filldraw[draw=blue,bottom color=blue!40,top color=gray!30]
        (11,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    \node[text width=4cm, font=\small,right] at (13,0.5)
        {Water and steam\\(secondary loop)};
    \filldraw[draw=blue,fill=blue!10] (21,0) rectangle ++(2,1);
    \node[text width=4cm, font=\small,right] at (23,0.5)
        {Water\\(cooling loop)};
\end{scope}
% 2nd loop --------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{scope}[xshift=7.25cm,yshift=3cm]
    % vessel left
    \filldraw[draw=blue,bottom color=blue!40,top color=gray!30]
        (0,0) to[out=-20,in=200] (3.5,0) --
        (3.5,4.5) to[out=120,in=60] (0,4.5) -- (0,0);
    % vessel right
    \filldraw[draw=blue,bottom color=blue!40,top color=gray!30,xshift=7cm]
        (0,0) to[out=-20,in=200] (3.5,0) --
        (3.5,5) to[out=120,in=60] (0,5) -- (0,0);
    % circuits
    \draw[draw=blue,double=blue!40,double distance=4pt]
      (1.75,-0.3) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(7,0) -- ++(0,1);
    \draw[draw=blue,double=gray!30,double distance=4pt]
        (1.75,5.38) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(4,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(3,0) -- ++(0,-1.5);
    % arrows
    \draw[arrows2loop] (3.5,-1.3) -- (3,-1.3);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (1.75,-0.9) -- (1.75,-0.4);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (4.5,6.38) -- (5,6.38);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (7,7.38) -- (7.5,7.38);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (8.75,6.4) -- (8.75,5.9);
    \draw[arrows2loop] (8.75,-0.4) -- (8.75,-0.9);
    %
    \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,3}
        \draw[arrows2loop,xshift=7cm] (\x,3) -- (\x,2.5);
    % labels
    \draw[annotline] (2.5,-1.3) -- ++(3.5,1.3)
        node[text width=1cm,font=\small,above] {Liquid};
    \draw[annotline] (2.5,6.38) -- ++(3.5,-1.3)
        node[text width=1cm,font=\small,below] {Vapor};
    % pump
    \begin{scope}[xshift=160,yshift=-40]
        \filldraw[fill=blue!20,draw=blue] (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
        \node[below,font=\small] at (0,-0.5) {Pump};
        \filldraw[fill=blue!40,draw=blue,yshift=-0.5cm]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=blue!40,draw=blue,yshift=+0.5cm,rotate=180]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=blue!40,draw=blue,xshift=+0.5cm,rotate=90]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=blue!40,draw=blue,xshift=-0.5cm,rotate=-90]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
    \end{scope}
    % generator ...
    \draw[xshift=6.5cm,draw=gray,double=gray!10,double distance=4pt] 
        (3,4) -- ++(2,0);
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (1.8,4) -- (3.0,3.3) -- (3.0,4.7) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (1.5,4) -- (2.5,3.4) -- (2.5,4.6) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (1.2,4) -- (2  ,3.5) -- (2  ,4.5) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[xshift=6.5cm,fill=orange!10,draw=orange] 
        (4.5,3.3) rectangle (7.3,4.7);
    %labels
    \node[text width=3cm, text centered,font=\small] at (1.75,4) 
        {Steam generator\\ (heat change)};
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (8.8,5) {Turbine};
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (12.4,4) {Alternator};
    % transmission lines
    \node (aa) at (11.1,4.6) {};
    \node (bb) at (11.6,4.6) {};
    \node (cc) at (12.1,4.6) {};
    \node (dd) at (12.6,4.6) {};
    \node (ee) at (13.1,4.6) {};
    \node (ff) at (13.6,4.6) {};

\end{scope}
% 3 loop --------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{scope}[xshift=23cm,yshift=1cm]
    % circuit
    \draw[draw=blue,double=blue!10,double distance=4pt]
      (1,2.5) -- ++(-8.5,0) -- ++(0,+1.5) -- ++(8.5,0);
    % arrows
    \draw[arrows3loop] (-5.5,2.5) -- (-6,2.5);
    \draw[arrows3loop] (-1.5,2.5) -- (-2,2.5);
    \draw[arrows3loop] (-6,4) -- (-5.5,4);
    \draw[arrows3loop] (-2,4) -- (-1.5,4);
    % tower
    \filldraw[draw=gray,fill=gray!20] (1,7) to[out=270,in=80]
                  (0,0) to[out=-20,in=200]
                  (6,0) to[out=100,in=270]
                  (5,7);
    \filldraw[draw=gray,fill=gray!40] (1,7) to[out=30,in=150]
                  (5,7) to[out=200,in=-20]
                  (1,7);
    % labels
    \node[text width=3cm, text centered,font=\small] at (3,3.5)
        {Cooling\\tower};
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (-3.5,1.5)
        {Cooling\\water};
    \node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (-6,3.25)
        {Condenser};
    % pump
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-10,yshift=115]
        \filldraw[fill=purple!20,draw=purple] (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
        \node[below,font=\small] at (0,-0.5) {Pump};
        \filldraw[fill=purple!40,draw=purple,yshift=-0.5cm]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=purple!40,draw=purple,yshift=+0.5cm,rotate=180]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=purple!40,draw=purple,xshift=+0.5cm,rotate=90]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
        \filldraw[fill=purple!40,draw=purple,xshift=-0.5cm,rotate=-90]
            (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
%1 loop --------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=4cm]
% Reactor vessel
\filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!10] (0,-0.5) to[out=-20,in=200]
              (3.5,-0.5) --
              (3.5,4.5) to[out=160,in=20]
              (0,4.5) --
              (0,-0.5);
% === circuit =========
\draw[draw=red,double=red!10,double distance=4pt,rounded corners=2pt]
  (0.1,1) --  ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-3) -- ++(5,0) -- ++(0,1.5) --
  ++(3,0) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(-3.7,0);

\draw [line width=2pt, dash pattern=on 4pt off 2pt,dash phase=\x/10*6pt,red!80,rounded corners=2pt] (0.1,1) --  ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-3) -- ++(5,0) -- ++(0,1.5) --   ++(3,0) -- ++(0,2) -- ++(-3.7,0);
% === =========
% Pressurizer
\draw[draw=red,double=red!10,double distance=4pt] (4.2,1.6) -- ++(0,0.8);
\filldraw[draw=green,bottom color=red!40,top color=green!20]
              (4,2.4) to[out=-20,in=200]
              (4.5,2.4) --
              (4.5,3.6) to[out=160,in=20]
              (3.9,3.6) --
              (3.9,2.4);
% === arrows =========
%\draw[arrows1loop] (-0.7,1) -- (-0.2,1);
%\draw[arrows1loop] (-0.9,-0.5) -- (-0.9,0);
%\draw[arrows1loop] (0.7,-2) -- (0.2,-2);
%\draw[arrows1loop] (4.5,1.5) -- (5,1.5);
%\draw[arrows1loop] (7.1,0.5) -- (7.1,0);
%\draw[arrows1loop] (5.5,-0.5) -- (5,-0.5);
% === =========

% pump
\begin{scope}[xshift=75,yshift=-55,fill=red!20,draw=red]
    \filldraw (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
    \node[below,font=\small] at (0,-0.5) {Pump};
    \filldraw[yshift=-0.5cm] (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
    \filldraw[yshift=+0.5cm,rotate=180]
        (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
    \filldraw[xshift=+0.5cm,rotate=90]
        (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
    \filldraw[xshift=-0.5cm,rotate=-90]
        (0,0) arc (240:180:0.4cm)  arc (200:280:0.4cm) ;
\end{scope}
% reactor core
\filldraw[fill=red!30,draw=red] (0.7,0) rectangle (2.8,2);

% control rods
\foreach \x in {1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5}
  \draw[draw=gray,double=gray!50,double distance=0.5pt] (\x,0.3) -- (\x,3.7);

%labels
\draw[annotline] (0.6,0.5) -- ++(-3.3,-1.5)
    node[text width=1cm,font=\small,left] {Reactor core};
\node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small] at (1.75,5.4) {Reactor vessel};
\draw[annotline] (0.9,2.8) -- ++(-3.3,1.5)
    node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small,left=-8pt] {Control\\rods};
\draw[annotline] (4.2,3.7) -- ++(0.5,1.5)
    node[text width=2cm, text centered,font=\small,above] {Pressurizer};
\draw[annotline] (3.9,1.5) -- ++(1.3,-0.6)
    node[text width=2.4cm, text centered,below=-2pt,font=\small]
        {Water coolant (\num{330}{\textdegree})};
\draw[annotline] (-0.1,-2) -- ++(-0.3,-0.6)
    node[text width=2.4cm, text centered,below=-2pt,font=\small]
        {Water coolant (\num{280}{\textdegree})};
\end{scope}
% clouds ----------------------------------
\begin{scope}[xshift=26cm,yshift=10cm, fill=blue!10, draw=blue,
    decoration={bumps,segment length=0.5cm}]
    \filldraw[yshift=-1.5cm,rotate=-25,decorate]
        (0,0) -- ++(-0.4,1.25)-- ++(-0.1,0.75)-- ++(0.2,0.5)-- ++(0.3,0.5)--
        ++(0.3,-0.5)-- ++(0.2,-0.5)-- ++(-0.1,-0.75)-- ++(-0.4,-1.25);
    \filldraw[xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-2cm,rotate=-30,decorate]
        (0,0) -- ++(-0.4,1.25)-- ++(-0.1,0.75)-- ++(0.2,0.5)-- ++(0.3,0.5)--
        ++(0.3,-0.5)-- ++(0.2,-0.5)-- ++(-0.1,-0.75)-- ++(-0.4,-1.25);
    \filldraw[xshift=-1.05cm,yshift=-2.15cm,rotate=-20,decorate]
        (0,0) -- ++(-0.4,1.25)-- ++(-0.1,0.75)-- ++(0.2,0.5)-- ++(0.3,0.5)--
        ++(0.3,-0.5)-- ++(0.2,-0.5)-- ++(-0.1,-0.75)-- ++(-0.4,-1.25);
    %labels
    \node[text width=1cm, text centered,font=\small] at (0.2,1.5) {Water vapor};
\end{scope}

% palo della luce
\begin{scope}[xscale=0.2,xshift=113cm,yshift=19cm,line width=1pt,brown]
    \draw (0,0) -- (-6,-6)
          (0,0) -- ( 6,-6)
          (-1,-1) -- ( 1,-1)
          (-1,-1) -- ( 2,-2)
          ( 1,-1) -- (-2,-2)
          (-2,-2) -- ( 2,-2)
          (-2,-2) -- ( 3,-3)
          ( 2,-2) -- (-3,-3)
          ( 3,-3) -- (-3,-3)
          (-3,-3) -- ( 4,-4)
          ( 3,-3) -- (-4,-4)
          ( 4,-4) -- (-4,-4)
          (-4,-4) -- ( 5,-5)
          ( 4,-4) -- (-5,-5)
          ( 5,-5) -- (-5,-5)
          (-6,-6) -- ( 0,-5.2)
          ( 6,-6) -- ( 0,-5.2);
    \draw (-1.5,-1.5) -- (-4,-1.5) -- (-1,-1)
          ( 1.5,-1.5) -- ( 4,-1.5) -- ( 1,-1);
    \path (-4,-1.4) node (a) {}
          ( 4,-1.4) node (b) {};
    \draw[line width=1pt,brown] (-3.5,-3.5) -- (-7.5,-3.5) -- (-3,-3)
                                ( 3.5,-3.5) -- ( 7.5,-3.5) -- ( 3,-3);
    \path (-7.5,-3.4) node (c) {}
          ( 7.5,-3.4) node (d) {}
          (-5.5,-3.4) node (e) {}
          ( 5.5,-3.4) node (f) {};
\end{scope}
% transmission lines
\draw[dashed,gray] (c) -- (aa)
                   (a) -- (bb)
                   (e) -- (cc)
                   (b) -- (dd)
                   (f) -- (ee)
                   (d) -- (ff);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

### Document Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[margin=15mm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \animategraphics[autoplay,loop]{10}{anim}{}{}
        \caption{reactor cycle}
    \end{figure}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

### Output

(again created with *[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)*)

[image]

Comment: As an alternative to using the `decorations` library for drawing lots of circles, you can also use a `dash pattern` with an `on` length of `0pt` together with `line cap=round` (see [Dotted lines in TikZ with round dots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101262/dotted-lines-in-tikz-with-round-dots)). That's much faster.

Comment: @Jake: That's a very good suggestion, as it will also work for rectacles, like in the OP's example. I'll try it out tomorrow.