# Draw background of water in cone

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

According to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101442/drawing-water-particles-in-a-water-column-tikz/101464#101464) I want to draw a partial background in a cone like this but it seems hard to me take the background from the code in the previous answer.
[image]

then tweak it until it looks like this:
[image]

I can do the dotted lines and vertical lines, but I have some trouble making the water falling down, i would like it seems like clouds or any idea for this?

**My work:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,important line/.style={thick}]
\draw [opacity=1,important line] (-2,4) -- (2,4) -- (0,0) -- cycle;%big triangle
\draw [important line,fill=white,opacity=1] (0,4) circle (2cm and 0.4cm);%top of cone
\draw [fill=blue!20!white,opacity=1] (-1.49,2.98) -- (1.49,2.98) -- (0,0) -- cycle;%smmall triangle
\draw [fill=blue!10!white,opacity=1,] (0,3) circle (1.49cm and 0.3cm); %top of small cone
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (0,4) --(2,4); %dashed lines
\draw (1,4.18) node{\scriptsize $ 2 $}; % number
\draw[dashed] (0,2.98) -- (1.49,2.98); %dashed line
\draw (0.745,3.12) node{\scriptsize $ r $}; % r
\draw[|<->|] (2.4,0) -- (2.4,4); %lenght indicator
\draw[white, fill=white] (2.3,1.75) rectangle (2.5,2.25); %an empty box for the space in middle
\draw (2.4,2) node{\scriptsize $ 4 $}; %a number
\draw[|<->|] (1.65,0) -- (1.65,2.98); %lenght indicator
\draw[white, fill=white] (1.45,1.24) rectangle (1.65,1.74);%white rectangle for a space in middle
\draw (1.65,1.49) node{\scriptsize $ h $};% h
\draw[gray,ultra thick] (-3,4) -- (-3,4.5)--(-2.5,4.8); %shower 
\draw[gray,fill=gray] (-2.35,4.8) circle (5pt); %here the rectangle must join at middle with circle
\draw[gray,fill=gray,rotate=-45] (-2.35,4.7) rectangle (-2.15,5.2);%bad rectangle, the rotate option moved the rectangle
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result: [image]

Comment: Can you sow us your code ?

Comment: Tikz ? PGF ? What have you coded so far,...

Comment: @SebastienComtois I've tried change the code of the answer in link for show one frame and then draw blank images above the frame but I can't modify the code from the answer to get just one frame

Comment: Post the code for what you can do here. It is better to ask a self-contained question. And you said you've got the dotted lines added, so you can show us that.

Comment: @cfr thanks for the suggestion, I have eddited with my work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This shows one way to modify [Claudio's Fiandrino's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101464/) to fill the cone and one way to create cloud shapes from the shower.

The shading/bubbles for the fill are adapted for use in a single, still image by removing overlays, modifying the area filled and clipping the result.

The cloud shapes are created as nodes using the `shapes.symbols` library as the basis for a new style `cloud drop`. This is shaded with the colours from Claudio's water shading.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
% code from Claudio Fiandrino's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101464/
\makeatletter
% original code in
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88040/how-can-we-draw-christmas-animations-with-tikz#88042
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{water}{\pgfpoint{-0.15cm}{0.4cm}}{%
  rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
  color(0.35cm)=(tikz@ball!35!white);
  color(0.75cm)=(tikz@ball!80!white);
  rgb(1cm)=(1,1,1)
}
\tikzoption{water color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{water}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
% original code by Jake:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85743/tikz-pgf-switching-off-shading#85750
\def\tikz@falsetext{false}
\tikzset{
    shade/.code={
        \edef\tikz@temp{#1}%
        \ifx\tikz@temp\tikz@falsetext%
            \tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadefalse}%
        \else%
            \tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}%
        \fi
    }
}
\makeatother
% still Claudio's code
\tikzset{%
  water particle/.style={
    circle,
    inner sep=2pt,
    shading=water,
    water color=#1,
  },
  water cold particle/.style={
    water particle=blue!30!white
  },
  water warm particle/.style={
    water particle=blue!40!cyan!80!black
  },
  water hot particle/.style={
    water particle=cyan!60!black
  },
  cloud drop/.style={
    cloud,
    cloud puffs=6,
    inner color=blue!20!white,
    outer color=cyan!60!black,
    aspect=2,
    inner sep=2.5pt,
  },
}

\begin{document}
% original code from Luis Felipe: question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290797/
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,important line/.style={thick}]
  \draw [opacity=1,important line] (-2,4) -- (2,4) -- (0,0) -- cycle;%big triangle
  \draw [important line,fill=white,opacity=1] (0,4) circle (2cm and 0.4cm);%top of cone
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (1.49,2.98) arc (0:180:1.49cm and 0.3cm) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    % simplified version of Claudio's code
    \shade[bottom color=cyan!60!black, top color=blue!20!white] (-1.5,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,3.3);

    \foreach \hotparticles in {1,...,70}{
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\xpos{4*\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ypos{2*\pgfmathresult}
      \node[water hot particle] at (\xpos,\ypos) {};
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\xpos{-4*\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ypos{2*\pgfmathresult}
      \node[water hot particle] at (\xpos,\ypos) {};
    }
    \foreach \warmparticles in {1,...,45}{
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\xpos{4*\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ypos{2*\pgfmathresult+1}
      \node[water warm particle] at (\xpos,\ypos) {};
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\xpos{-4*\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ypos{2*\pgfmathresult+1}
      \node[water warm particle] at (\xpos,\ypos) {};
    }

    \foreach \coldparticles in {1,...,25}{
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\xpos{4*\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ypos{2*\pgfmathresult+2.5}
      \node[water cold particle] at (\xpos,\ypos) {};
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\xpos{-4*\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathrandom{}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ypos{2*\pgfmathresult+2.5}
      \node[water cold particle] at (\xpos,\ypos) {};
    }
  \end{scope}
  \draw  (-1.49,2.98) -- (0,0) -- (1.49,2.98);%smmall triangle
  \draw [blue] (0,3) circle (1.49cm and 0.3cm); %top of small cone
  \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (0,4) --(2,4); %dashed lines
  \draw (1,4.18) node{\scriptsize $ 2 $}; % number
  \draw[dashed] (0,2.98) -- (1.49,2.98); %dashed line
  \draw (0.745,3.12) node{\scriptsize $ r $}; % r
  \draw[|<->|] (2.4,0) -- (2.4,4); %lenght indicator
  \draw[white, fill=white] (2.3,1.75) rectangle (2.5,2.25); %an empty box for the space in middle
  \draw (2.4,2) node{\scriptsize $ 4 $}; %a number
  \draw[|<->|] (1.65,0) -- (1.65,2.98); %lenght indicator
  \draw[white, fill=white] (1.45,1.24) rectangle (1.65,1.74);%white rectangle for a space in middle
  \draw (1.65,1.49) node{\scriptsize $ h $};% h
  \draw[gray,ultra thick] (-3,4) -- (-3,4.5)--(-2.5,4.8); %shower
  \foreach \i in {(-1.7,4.5),(-1.1,4.1),(-.6,3.7)} \node [cloud drop] at \i {};
  \draw [important line] (-2,4) arc (180:360:2cm and 0.4cm);%top of cone
  \draw[gray,fill=gray] (-2.35,4.8) circle (5pt); %here the rectangle must join at middle with circle
  \draw[gray,fill=gray] (-2.35,4.8) -- ++(45:.25) -- ++(-45:.25) -- ++(-135:.5) -- ++(135:.25) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: clouds]

Comment: Nice solution, but when I do `rotate` in the rectangle it moves to the top right, I would like it just be above the circle in the left as in a shower

Comment: Sorry. I don't really know what you mean. Which rectangle?

Comment: `\draw[gray,fill=gray,rotate=-45] (-2.35,4.7) rectangle (-2.15,5.2);%bad rectangle, the rotate option moved the rectangle`  in the las line before `\end{tikzpicture}` This rectangle must to be in left side,  above the circle

Comment: Oh. You want `rotate around={-45:(<x>,<y>)}` for whatever point you want to rotate relative to. The origin is the default.

Comment: Personally, I'd use `\draw[gray,fill=gray] (-2.35,4.8) -- ++(45:.25) -- ++(-45:.25) -- ++(-135:.5) -- ++(135:.25) -- cycle;` instead. But I find it a pain to figure out what I want for the point of rotation.

Comment: See edit @LuisFelipe.

Comment: now is perfect. you're great.